# vue router scroll behavior give hint to route values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a route that can have the following parameters and query:

parent route: `path: "/:locale(en|jp)?"`
products route: `path: 'products/:category/:page?'`
query in product can be:

```
{
  q:search string for filter,
  size:size value for filter,
  color:color value for filter,
  designer:designer value for filter
  sort:sort value
}
```

Example of the app is [here](https://spa-facet.herokuapp.com/de/products/men?color=blue)

My question is that when I change size, color or designer I would like to return `savedPosition` from [scrollBehavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html), in any other case it would return `{x:0,y:0}`

Is there a way to do this without checking all query values from `to` and `from` and making the scrollBehavior function needlessly bloated and instead pass a hint when pushing the route from the function that sets color, size or designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not have to create complex logic in scrollBehavior I just have it keep returning `{x:0,Y:0}` and created the following function:

```
export const pushRoute = (route, component, keepScrollPosition = true) => {
  const pos = {
    top: window.scrollY,
    left: window.scrollX,
  };
  component.$router.push(route);

  if (keepScrollPosition) {
    Promise.resolve().then(
      () => { window.scrollTo(pos); },
    );
  }
};
```

From my component I call it in the following way:

```
pushRoute(
  {
    ...this.$route,
    query,
  }, this, true,
);
```